# Get remaining stock from Amazon Listing

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

Been working on Amazon Product API to fetch basic details of product listings.
Details I am trying to get are :

- Product Name
- Price
- Availability (Yes/No)
- Remaining stock - When the stock runs low.

You might have seen that type of listings, where the quantity is low, it starts showing 5 Items left. and so on.

Eg: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dome-Enclosure-Foscam-Indoor-Cameras/dp/B00BMVRNHE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1431042188&sr=8-1&keywords=dome+enclosure+foscam

`Only 9 left in stock.`

I could get every other details except the no of stock left. Since this is a publically available data, I mean, this can be fetched out by curl even without logging in (that wont solve my problem in this case though), so I guess there must be an option in API to get that.

Comment: Things could have been better atleast if they had a good documentation. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Amazon Product API doesn't provide this information.

Although you can strip the HTML sequence on the product page which shows the number of items left in stock and use it on your website, I don't think it's legal.

Comment: What a shame that they are not providing PUBLIC content through the API.

Comment: What other public data are they not providing?

Comment: The shipping cost, for example. Although it is not always easy to have it calculated while fetching the product from the API (it depends on location, the amazon user type, etc). And I've noticed that the prices on the product webpage and the one fetched from the API are not always the same. Probably they have two different storages.